# What's wrong with insertion operator overloading? (<< operator)

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword, insertion

I have to overload the insertion operator in order to view my class objects in matrix format. I wrote the code but something's wrong. When I include this to my code and trying to build, compiler gives me tons of errors; when I commented that part out, the errors are gone and program works correctly. Here is the code:

```
    template <class itemType> 
ostream & operator<< (ostream & os, const Storage2D<itemType> & rhs)
{
    node<itemType>* ptrRow = rhs.head;
    node<itemType>* ptrColumn = rhs.head;
    for(; ptrColumn->down != NULL; ptrColumn = ptrColumn->down)
    {
        ptrRow = ptrColumn;
        for(; ptrRow->right != NULL; ptrRow = ptrRow->right)
        {
            os << ptrRow->info << setw(10);
        }
        os << ptrRow->info << setw(10) << endl;
    }

    return os;
}
```

Here is how I tried to use overloading from main function:

```
Storage2D<double> m(row, column); 
cout << m;
```

It is not the member function of class Storage2D, it is written outside of the scope of class Storage2D in the implementation file.

It would be great if you help me, thanks in advance.

EDIT: Here is the rest of my code. The Storage2D.h file:

```
template <class itemType>
struct node
{
    itemType info;
    node* right;
    node* down;

    node()
    {}

    node(itemType data, node* r = NULL, node* d = NULL)
    {
        info = data;
        right = r;
        down = d;
    }
};

template <class itemType>
class Storage2D
{
public:
    Storage2D(const int & , const int & );      //constructor
    //~Storage2D();                             //destructor
    //Storage2D(const Storage2D & );                //deep copy constructor

private:
    node<itemType>* head;
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream & os, const Storage2D & rhs);

#include "Storage2D.cpp"
```

Comment: We need to see the error messages.  Ideally you would also show us a small (< 100 lines) self-contained test case that demonstrates the problem; the code you've shown is not enough to know what is wrong.

Comment: As a rule, when you ask how to fix a problem of the nature of "if I do X I get errors", you should include in the question a copy of at least the first of those errors.

Comment: at a guess you need to make the operator a friend, but we need the error to be sure.

Comment: The errors I get are briefly these: 
(34): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

(34): error C2065: 'os' : undeclared identifier

(34): error C2059: syntax error : 'const'

(4): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '&'

(4): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
(4): error C2086: 'int ostream' : redefinition
(4): error C2065: 'os' : undeclared identifier
(4): error C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
(4): error C2059: syntax error : 'const'

Comment: Sorry for ugly formatting of errors. @juanchopanza helped me to solve the problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`head` is private so the operator needs to be a friend so it can access that data member. It also needs to be declared as a function template since Storage2D is a class template:

```
#include <iostream> // for std::ostream

template <class itemType>
class storage2D {
// as before
template <typename T> 
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream & os, const Storage2D<T> & rhs);
};

// declaration
template <typename T> 
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream & os, const Storage2D<T> & rhs);
```

Note that I have explicitly used `std::ostream`, since `ostream` is in the `std` namespace.

Comment: This fix helped a lot of errors but still 4 error to go. I guess it does not recognize ostream& as a return type. Should I include some libraries to use it?<pre>

syntax error : missing ';' before '&' 
syntax error : missing ';' before '<end Parse>' 
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

All for this line: 
ostream& operator<< (ostream & os, const Storage2D<T> & rhs);</pre>

Comment: @MertToka It could be that you haven't included <iostream>, and you probably need to use the `std` namespace. I edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, it finally works. Btw, i am sorry for bad editing of my commands. I am totally stranger to the HTML codes.